# Create table with 3 foreign keys and no private attributes in sequelize

Tags: database, sequelize.js

What is the best way to create a relationship table with 3 foreign keys and no personal attributes . 
I want to create a relationship table `teacher_subject_allocation` which contains `subject` , `teacher` and `section`

`subject.belongsToMany(teacher, {through: 'teacher_subject_allocation'})`

```
teacher.belongsToMany(section, {through: 'teacher_subject_allocation'})
```

Comment: What do you mean by no personal attribute?

Comment: no attributes of its own

Answer (score 1):

```
//main tables 
//(foreignKey contains field name in association table)
subject.hasOne(teacher_subject_allocation , { foreignKey: 'subject_id' });
teacher.hasOne(teacher_subject_allocation , { foreignKey: 'teacher_id' });
section.hasOne(teacher_subject_allocation , { foreignKey: 'section_id' });

//association table 
//(targetKey is PK of main table, foreignKey is field of current table)
teacher_subject_allocation.belongsTo(subject, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'subject_id' });
teacher_subject_allocation.belongsTo(teacher, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'teacher_id' });
teacher_subject_allocation.belongsTo(section, { targetKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'section_id' });
```

Comment: but "teacher_subject_allocation" does not exists .
belongsToMany creates automatically relationship table .

Comment: It will not create if you create it yourself, create `teacher_subject_allocation` with these 3 columns and apply the associations

Comment: what if i dont want to create the model . Any other way ?

Comment: And even if i create it manually , it will create another attribute "id" which i dont want .

Comment: Tried your thing . 
id field is also created but i want primary key to be the combination of all three foreign keys .